# How do I know if a ceiling fan with light and the switch are wired correctly?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

There was a old ceiling fan with light and remote in a bedroom of my house that didn't work.  It also had a switch with 2 knobs that pushed in and turned labeled `motor control` and `300 w perm instld incand` it had 3 wires coming out of it red, black, and yellow, but the yellow wasn't connected.

Coming from the box was red and black which are both hot and were connected to the switch, and white.

So in the ceiling I have 3 cables, 2 of them black and white, and the 3rd is red, white and black.

So I bought a Hampton Bay 52" Ceiling fan with light and remote.  I connected all the wires like the manual said . Nothing would work. So I connected it without the remote receiver and when I turn back on the power it comes on. But with no remote I cant control it.

I purchased a Lutron fan control & Dimmer Skylark s2-lfsqh-wh. And I cannot get it to connect to the fixture.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've described, this is what I *think* you're wiring *should* look like.  Keep in mind, this is just a guess. I can't see what's going on, and I'm an internet away, so I can't touch/measure/test anything.

[image: My guess at wiring]

The wiring diagram for the switch, can be found in the [installation instructions](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/0301050A.pdf).

> [image: Wiring Diagram from Installation Guide]

If you provide images, and/or a better description of what wires and cables are in each box. I'll be able to provide a better guess, as to how this should be wired.

## NOTE:

The diagram is based on *your* description, and is my best **guess** as to what your wiring looks like.  If you're not sure what to do, or feel like this project is over your head. Do not hesitate to contact a local licensed Electrician.

Comment: YeeHA everything works, except the fan doesnt turn off and i am hearing a very short buzzing noise about every two seconds.  Becides that its all good.  Any suggestions?  And Thank you

Comment: If the fan doesn't turn off, something is wrong. You should not be hearing any buzzing. Call an Electrician.

Comment: I haven't turned the power back on in that room and I am going to call an Electrician. The only thing I can think of is that none of the wires are grounded. Could that be the cause?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. I took a guess at what your wiring looked like, without actually seeing it or testing anything.  My guess could be completely incorrect, and I can't see how you've hooked things up, so there is no way for me to know for sure what the problem is.  If you included some photos, that might help. Your best bet is to find somebody that knows what they're doing, and can actually be there.