# what are the little dots on wiring diagrams?

Tags: electrical, wiring

There are little dots along the lines in many wiring diagrams, like in response to the question ["How do I know if a ceiling fan with light and the switch are wired correctly?"](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/31961/33).  Some of these seem to indicate a junction with another wire, or a color change, but some are just in the middle of a single color wire.  What does this indicate?

Also, why does the color change along a wire in a diagram?

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about the orange/yellow dots in this?

[image: Wiring Diagram]

These are not standard wiring diagrams, they're just drawings that Tester101 makes to make his answers easy to understand.

He appears to be using the orange/yellow dots to indicate splicing the wires together using a [wire-nut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist-on_wire_connector).

Comment: And the white wire with a black color change near the end is a white wire with black tape on the end to mark a switched hot.

Comment: Yes, those are the dots, but why have them along a single color line like the orange ones red and green lines?

Comment: @curiousburke Because you're splicing two wires of the same color

Comment: oh, because the components have wires that you need to wire to.  I didn't realize wiring diagrams were that realistic.  Thanks all!